# Cannot disown Z shell variable

Tags: shell, zsh

The following Z shell code works:

```
emacs &  
disown emacs
```

but the following does not:

```
a="emacs"  
"$a" &  
disown "$a"
```

The latter gives an error from disown saying that it could not find a job named emacs. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you always want to immediately disown the process, you could use `&|` or `&!` rather than plain `&` to run the process in the background and disown it in one step.

If you really want to do this as a separate step, you can place single quotes around the argument for `disown`:

```
disown '"$a"'
```

Calling `jobs` after the command is started would reveal that eliminating the quotes and replacing the variable aren't happening until after the job is named, so you need to include those when naming the job which you want to disown.

Comment: Interesting. So the job is created *before* parameter expansion?